# Python removing a function from its tuple

Tags: python

sorry for the lousy title, its hard to explain it in one line.

well, i have this code, and i run a function in it.
after running this function i receive a tuple like so :

```
(Position(15,20),425)
```

now i want 3 vars - x,y,z to get these numbers.
i tried :

```
x,y,z = val
```

it doesnt work.
i tried to the it from a different approach,
still doesnt get it, i get this error :

```
ValueError : need more than 2 values to unpack
```

so i realized i need to break that position out.
i have no clue how to do it...

can someone help me? thanks

Answer (score 3):

(assuming that `Position(15,20)` is iterable and contains exactly two items) You just need to put parenthesis around the first two variables.

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> tup = ((1,2),3)
>>> (x,y),z = tup
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
>>> z
3
>>>
```

Comment: I guess his position is a custom class instance

Comment: More useful to understand. Since you're assigning from a two-item tuple, you need to assign to two items. In the case of [iCodez's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2555451/icodez) answer, the two items are the tuple `(a,b)` and the number `c`. The tuple `(a,b)` takes its values from the first element of your tuple, which is the result of your function call (luckily also a tuple). The number `c` takes its value from the second element of your tuple.

Comment: @user3050392 - Happy to have helped!  Please don't forget to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).  Doing so lets people know that this problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You Position should be iterable, returning (15, 20), then you can unpack it as well

```
class Position (object):
    def __init__(self, x, y): self.x, self.y = x, y
    def __iter__(self): return iter((self.x, self.y))

(x, y), z = (Position(15,20),245)
# equals x = 15; y = 20; z = 245
```

Comment: Better yet, `Position` should be a `namedtuple`.

Comment: @9000 *can* be ;) this snippet shows how this can be implemented for an arbitrary class

Answer (score 0):

Without making any assumptions about `Position` you can do:

```
pos, z = (Position(15,20),245)
```

Whether you can do

```
x, y = pos
```

depends on the nature of `Position`.  As other answers suggest, if it is a named tuple this works.  Increasingly Python code is using Namedtuples to return values like this.  The example used in the documentation is for a `Point(x,y)`.